# easy SublimeText question regarding pygame module

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sublimetext3

I've been using SublimeText on OSX without issue... until I tried to import pygame.  A simple few lines of code like:

```py
print("Hello")
import sys
import pygame
```

gets the following output:

```
    Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrewjmiller/Desktop/python_work/new_file.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/andrewjmiller/Desktop/python_work/new_file.py"]
[dir: /Users/andrewjmiller/Desktop/python_work]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/andrewjmiller/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

But... I do have pygame installed, as evidenced here:

```
iMac:~ AndyTheAdmin$ python3 -m pip install --user pygame==2.0.0.dev6
Requirement already satisfied: pygame==2.0.0.dev6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.0.dev6)
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled SublimeText3.  What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're falling victim to the difference between Python 2 and Python 3. In particular, note the line in the Sublime diagnostic output that says what command it was that failed:

```
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/andrewjmiller/Desktop/python_work/new_file.py"]
```

The `Python.sublime-build` file that ships with Sublime tells the OS to execute the command `python`.

In your example where it works (or rather where you get confirmation that the library is installed):

```
iMac:~ AndyTheAdmin$ python3 -m pip install --user pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Here you're executing `python3`. Dollars to donuts if you were to type `python --version`   in the terminal, it's Python 2 that Sublime is executing. The different versions of Python keep their packages in different locations, which is why it works in one place and not the other.

Assuming that this is the case, the solution is to use a build that executes `python3` instead. If you're already using a custom build system, then you can modify it directly. If you're using the build that ships with Sublime, the easiest way to make a new build is:

1. Use `View Package File` from the command palette and open `Python/Python.sublime-build` to see what the existing build system looks like, and copy the entire thing to the clipboard.
2. Use `Tools > Build System > New Build System`, replace the content with what you copied above, then swap the `python` for `python3` in the two `shell_cmd` lines so that they execute the version that you expect.
3. Save the file in the location that Sublime defaults to (should be your `User` package) as a `sublime-build` file with an appropriate name.

Once you save, the Build system will be made available. You can either select it from `Tools > Build System` to use it directly, or if you have the build system in that menu set to `Automatic` the next time you do a build Sublime should prompt you to pick the build to use since there is now new builds.

Comment: Fantastic....and thank you!  That was the issue, and I appreciate that your answer was easy for a newbie like me to follow.  Indeed, OSX was using 2.7, and when I created a new Build in Sublime that pointed to Python 3.8, everything worked out.   Much thanks!