# Had Matplotlib on Sublime Text, Now It's Gone

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext

I'm completely new at using Sublime Text. But, I was able to import and even use Matplotlib to create plots.

Now, I'm trying to run the same script I had before that worked perfectly, but it doesn't run anymore.

I get the message:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [easy SublimeText question regarding pygame module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59430307/easy-sublimetext-question-regarding-pygame-module)

Comment: it seems like the version of python interpreter used by sublime doesn't have the module installed. You can try to check python version, or try to run the .py file from command line to see if it works in that case and check the two python used are the same.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip install matplotlib`?

Comment: @1000Gbps I get: "pip: command not found" (I'm assuming this is in the terminal)

Comment: @Vincenzooo Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried running the code in the command window and it still doesn't run. The weirdest part is that the output has things that aren't even a part of my script... but they were a part of code that I was trying to run in another script. For example, I have "AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'" but I don't have numpy in this script at all. I also notice that anaconda3 and miniconda3 both appear in the path that shows below my error. These are programs I tried to download at one point but then delete. Is the problem me still having them?

Comment: @OdatNurd Sorry... I'm still trying to understand/follow it but I'll let you know! I don't understand how this all works yet.

Comment: @OdatNurd Ok, I followed the steps and created a new build system (replacing "python" with "python3") like the post suggests. But now, whether I select the build "Python", "Python3" or "Automatic", I still get an issue. When I use "Python3", I get an error. When I use the other two ("Automatic" or "Python"), I get no error and just "[Finished in 0.1s]". Just after saving the new build system I tried it, and I got the same message ("[Finished in 0.1s]"). The error has numpy in it when I'm only calling and using matplotlib, too.

Comment: If all you see in the output is that it finished, make sure that you're not picking the `Syntax Check` variant of the build system; that one compiles the code but doesn't run it. For verification, can you provide the build system that you're currently trying to use in your question?

Comment: Note also that if your program doesn't actually generate any output, then all you'll see is that it ran to completion.

Comment: @OdatNurd How can I check to see what build system I'm using? I can't find the file I saved it in but I know I typed and saved: {  "cmd": ["usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],  }. This is the one I should be using.

Comment: The current build system is shown with a check mark in the `Tools > Build System` menu; when that's set to `Automatic`, then you can use `Tools > Build With...` to get Sublime to prompt you to select the build system to use. In that case, the name of the build system you pick is the the one that's used, and it's based on the name of the `sublime-build` file.

Comment: @OdatNurd I see. The build system I'm using is Python3.

Comment: You say you're getting an error, but not what it is; is it the same error as in your question?

Comment: @OdatNurd Sorry for the delay in my responses- things have been getting busy this time of year. Hope you enjoyed the holidays!
I actually went back onto Sublime just now and everything seemed to have worked.... it feels like the error is gone. But the error was that I didn't have Matplotlib even though I was using it before. I think maybe it had to do with the Build System. I'm still not completely sure how this works but I'm going to save this information and use it if it happens again in the future. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (I'm doing this on VM with MacOS and SublimeText 3):

1. Press Cmd+Shift+P
2. Type in the field `Package Control: Install Package`. Press Enter and search for Matplotlib

---

On Ubuntu 18.04 (also VM):

1. Open the terminal
2. Type `python3 --version` to check if Python 3 is installed
3. If the above command returns the currently installed 3rd version, type `sudo apt install python3-pip`
4. If you are not sure you're lucky after the installation type `pip -V` to check if pip is actually installed
5. If the above command gives you a good output, then type `pip install matplotlib` and wait while `matplotlib` is installed
6. As last step type `pip list` to see the list of all installed packages. One of the lines will be for Matplotlib